# Visual Studio Xamarin free provisionning from XCode 7.3.1

Tags: xamarin

I requested free provisionning on XCode with a certain bundle id. I used the same bundle id in Info.plist (Visual Studio Xamarin). I am able to build my IOS projet, but when I try to run it in XCode simulator, I get:

2017-03-28 22:02:16.564 simctl[3496:33726] There was an error parsing the Info.plist for the bundle at URL Info.plist -- file:///Users/XXXXX/Desktop/Phoneword.IOS.app/
 NSCocoaErrorDomain - 3840
 {type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
0 : {contents = "NSDebugDescription"} = {contents = "Cannot parse a NULL or zero-length data"}
}
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.PL

My Info.plist is empty inside the app. Can someone help me ?

Comment: On Visual Studio open project properties for your iOS project and go to `iOS Application` tab. See what's written in `Identifier` box?

Comment: Application names: Phoneword, Identifier: com.XXXX, Devices: iPhone/iPod, Version 1, Buld 1.0, Deployment Target, 7.0, Launch Storyboard: LaunchScreen...

Comment: BTW I am using visual studio 2015

Comment: I have just noticed that the folder *.app size is 0 byte :(

Comment: I found this bug in bugzilla: [link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24421) Can someone tell me where I am suppose to get the app file on the mac then ?

Comment: You can get the .app file from the Cache on the Mac Build Host at path: `/Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/<appname>/<GUID>/bin/<platform>/<configuration>/